# How can I create an empty .html and .js file in windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I want to know if it is possible to create an empty .html and .js file inside on the Windows command line interface? If so, how do I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depends, if you're just looking to create two files with the correct extensions then the following should work:

```
type NUL > test.html
type NUL > test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows terminal command for creating a new file:

```
fsutil file createnew [filename with extension] 0
```

For example:

```
fsutil file createnew app.js 0
```